# transparency for heatmap in plotly

Tags: r, colors, plotly, transparency, heatmap

So I am creating heatmaps and I would like the lower end of the colour scale to be transparent in the plot.

For the sake of reproducibility lets use the volcano data set as our example.

```
p <- plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "heatmap", colors = c("blue", "blue", "green", "yellow", 
             "orange", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red"))
```

I would like to change both the blue values to be completely transparent colors.

Note: I don't want slightly less opaque blues, I would like a completely transparent color.

So far I have tried to use the `rgb()` function and setting the `alpha` variable to the value 0 and 1, however this has no effect on the color when the heatmap is printed to the Viewer.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks